# Conflict between similarly named resourcestrings and constants

Tags: delphi, resources, delphi-10.4-sydney

We have:

- a `uResourceTableFields.pas` unit defining consts for fieldnames
  this contained `SHours = 'tt_hours';`
- a `uResource.pas` unit containing resourcestrings
  These are use for the UI and are subject to translations

I added

```
SHours = 'Uren';
```

to `uResource.pas` and this compiled fine.

The next day I noticed code like

```
Result := AllocationData.FieldByName(SHours).AsFloat;
```

failed with 'field not found' ;-)
The resourcestring was substituted here!

How can we *automatically* prevent these kinds of conflicts at compile time?
It is not possible to limit our Uses clauses to either `uResourceTableFields` or `uResource`.

Comment: `uResourceTableFields.SHours` and `uResource.SHours`? If you only write `SHours`, this refers to the identifier in the most recently encountered unit in the `uses` lists.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand That would be quite an undertaking. I'd rather prevent (detect) the duplicate names.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking here. You cannot automatically prevent duplicate names. What you can do is use different prefix for all your constants, so that accidental collision cannot occur, or wrap them inside static class or record.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that this doesn't have anything in particular to do with `const` strings and `resourcestring`s. You can have `var A: Integer` in `Unit1.pas` and `var B: Integer` in `Unit2.pas` and you get the exact same situation. Or functions. Or types. Or ...

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand You have a point ;-) Still, I'm curious if this can be prevented other than 'manually'. Maybe with some additional initialization code at run time? But I doubt that, the const names don't exist at that stage.

Comment: Duplicate identifiers are a feature of the language and there are rules which compiler follows when resolving duplicate identifiers. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Fundamental_Syntactic_Elements_(Delphi) and http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Declarations_and_Statements_(Delphi)#Blocks_and_Scope there is nothing you can do at the runtime, because identifiers are resolved at compile time. Maybe some static analysis tools can help you, but, again just use different naming scheme.

Comment: ^^ this. Prefix your resource vars so you *know* that it is a resource string, something like Resource_SHours;

Comment: @whosrdaddy:  That makes the best sense to me.